# It is about reading XML file in android studio

Tags: android, xml, string

If I have XML file and it was wrote in Arabic, but my application supports 2 languages (Arabic & English), is there any way to change the sentences in **XML** file to English when the user changes the language of the app?

Answer (score 1):

I think `Official Documentation` is written in pretty well methodology -

So here I'm providing you that links - 
Let me entitle it as -

**Thing to be taken care of while you are developing an App with muti-language support**

- [Localization Checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/localization-checklist.html)
- [Writing style](https://material.io/guidelines/style/writing.html)
- [XLIFF - XML Localisation Interchange File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF)

Ps, First link is the parent of all, Go there - Its pretty interestring stuffs out there!

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is explained in the official [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should create `strings.xml` for Arabic and English languages

Comment: okay, i have already done it. but my XML file i want to read from it and display it in a list is in Arabic, so now,  
(( <idea id="2two">
      <title>اذهب للتسوق</title>
    </idea>))
this is one if the items in my XML file, but when i change the app language, still shown in Arabic, actually i tried to make this: 
 (( <title>@String:goForShopping</title>))
and i make this ((@String:goForShopping)) in the string.xml Arabic and English. i did not work!

Comment: in your strings.xml for Arabic you should write <string name="some_string">اذهب للتسوق</string> , and in your strings.xml for English you should write <string name="some_string">Translation_of_Arabic_string</string>.

Comment: thank you so much. I think that i am asking about another thing but i cant explained it! :|

Answer (score 0):

You can create different XML files for different languages. The app/android will choose in condition to the system language which XML too choose.

You just have to create a new folder called `values-ar` in `res/` where you put your Arabic `strings.xml`